# where query after context has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am using this in my data layer

```
public static IQueryable<Permission> ListAll()
{
    using (InventorySystemEntities context = new InventorySystemEntities(new ConfigurationManager().ConnectionString))
    {
        IQueryable<Permission> result = context.Permissions;
        return result;
    }
}
```

it should put all rows inside the result variable. however doing something like this, and it will result to context has been disposed..

```
permissionList = PermissionModel.ListAll();
chkListGeneral.DataSource = permissionList.Where(p => p.Parent == "General");
```

is there a way to filter the IQueryable without a context?

Comment: No. You need the provider for the IQueryable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is accessible only as long as the context that wraps it. Your method returns `IQueryable`, so the filter is trying to be "translated" to a DB query, but the underlying query provider no longer exists. You either need to specify the where condition while the context still exists, or force eager load (e.g. by calling `ToList()` on the `result` variable), return `IEnumerable` and filter the results in memory.

Comment: i have tried this already, calling Where from an IEnumerable<T> or List<T> returns method or operation not implemented.

Comment: Even when you simply change the return type to `IEnumerable<T>` and call `ToList()` on the `result`?